# Where is MessageDispatcherServlet in Spring Framework 4

Tags: spring, web-services

Can anyone tell me what, if anything, replaced MessageDispatcherServlet in version 4 of the Spring Framework?

Comment: Do you talk about the `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet`  from Spring Web Services?

Comment: yes.  is this still being used in version 4 or has it been replaced?

Comment: There is no and has never been a `MessageDispatcherServlet` in the Spring framework. That is part of Spring Web Services and there it still is available and used and will remain so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java Doc of Spring Web Service in current version (2.2.4), it is still there:

```
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
```

But of course it is part of [Spring-WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) not of Spring-Core

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

@see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/

Comment: i see that; however, is it still being used or has it been replaced?

Comment: I cant see any deprecated annotation. And it is still mentioned in the reference documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#message-dispatcher-servlet But in this chapter is also a hint for Servlet 3 enviroments with procamatic initialization